# Redis Sentinel myid

Tags: redis

Does anyone know how redis sentinel determines the value for 
`myid` in the config file?

I've created an image for deploying redis on my network but the Redis Sentinel values for `myid` are all duplicated, which is causing lots of log spam showing:

`[991] 30 Nov 20:56:48.639 * -dup-sentinel master mymaster 10.254.18.162 6379 #duplicate of 10.254.18.160:26379 or e2aa60902f872679221db15c4b414c7d5b3eca7c
[991] 30 Nov 20:56:48.639 * +sentinel sentinel 10.254.18.160:26379 10.254.18.160 26379 @ mymaster 10.254.18.162 6379`

Attempts at manually changing the value fail b/c the file rewrites itself with the old value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok well what I had to do was stop redis-sentinel, delete most of the config, including the myid line, and then start redis-sentinel back up. It generated a new id.